# Why can't I retrieve child elements from getElementsById on <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The output of the following code snippet

```
<body>
  <div id="hello">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <script>
    const node = document.getElementById('hello');
    console.log(node);
  </script>
</body>
```

is as follows

```
<div id="hello">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

This is expected behavior.

But if I change the element containing `id=hello` from `<div>` to `<p>`, it does not output the child elements.

```
<body>
  <p id="hello">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </p>
  <script>
    const node = document.getElementById('hello');
    console.log(node);
  </script>
</body>
```

Its output becomes

```
<p id="hello">
    </p>
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` elements cannot contain other *block* elements. A `<p>` ends when then next block element starts. That's just how HTML works. Thus your nested `<p>` ends the "parent" `<p>`, which isn't really a parent.

That's also why it's true that you don't have to close `<p>` elements. They close implicitly. Same goes for `<li>` and some others.